# How to overlay shadow with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

At first, Imma a noobie in CSS and know only bases.
I need to add few cards at the right side. And I made it but as you can see below a shadow doesn't overlay another cards. I found solution to use `absolute` position but I need to use bootstrap to it recombines on small screen.
It's my layout at this moment:

```css
.pm-tile {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.pm-tile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 1</div>
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 2</div>
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 3</div>
      <div class="row pm-tile">Test 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P. S. How can I make it using a bootstrap's div table? Or it's possible only with `absolute` position property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add in your :hover pseudo class the position: relative; then you can get the effect that you are looking for.

```css
.pm-tile {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.pm-tile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 1</div>
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 2</div>
        <div class="row pm-tile">Test 3</div>
      <div class="row pm-tile">Test 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because the z-index rule only works if the position is absolute, relative or fixed.

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks for explanation!